# Does NP ⊆ Co-NP imply NP = Co-NP?

Tags: complexity-theory

Does NP ⊆ Co-NP imply NP = Co-NP?

And also, does Co-NP ⊆ NP imply NP = Co-NP?

And does either statement imply P = NP?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: It’s a homework exercise about what happens if an NP-complete problem in coNP.

Comment: coNP = NP under Turing reductions, though it is not known if P=NP

Comment: NP=coNP is not known to imply P=NP. As for your other question (does NP$\subseteq$coNP imply NP=coNP), your guess is correct, and I am certain that you can prove it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

$L \in Co-NP$

$=> \overline{L} \in NP $

$=> \overline{L} \in Co-NP $

$=> L \in NP $

$=> Co-NP ⊆ NP $

$=> NP = Co-NP $